# CloudFormation how to export a variable

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-linux

The following is a part of our template. We export a path variable there. However, running from template, this does not work. If I SSH into the server and run the same line, it works and I can use gradle. But just from the template, it somehow doesn't get executed. The other `chmod` commands work, so the block is clearly execute. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
...
        "LaunchConfiguration": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                  "config": {
                    "packages": {
                      "yum": {
                        "java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel": []
                      }
                    },
                    "sources": {
                      "/opt": "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip",
                      "/home/ec2-user": "https://github.com/ABC/XYZ/archive/master.zip"
                    },
                    "files": {
                      "/tmp/gradle_config": {
                        "content": {
                          "Fn::Join": ["",
                            [
                              "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                              "chmod -R 755 gradle-3.4.1/\n",
                              "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle-3.4.1/bin\n" //<<<< This does not work
                            ]
                          ]
                        },
                        "mode": "000500",
                        "owner": "root",
                        "group": "root"
                      },
                      "/tmp/app_config": {
                        "content": {
                          "Fn::Join": ["",
                            [
                              "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                              "chmod -R 777 XYZ-master/\n"
                            ]
                          ]
                        },
                        "mode": "000500",
                        "owner": "root",
                        "group": "root"
                      }
                    },
                    "commands": {
                      "01_config": {
                          "command": "/tmp/gradle_config",
                           "cwd" : "/opt"
                      },
                      "02_config": {
                          "command": "/tmp/app_config",
                           "cwd" : "/home/ec2-user"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
            }, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. All those lines are executed as root user. The `export PATH...` therefore wasn't for my `ec2-user`. The way I handled is was by putting the path variable (globally) into the `/etc/environment` file.

In my code snippet, just replace

`"export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle-3.4.1/bin\n",`

with

`"echo \"PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle-3.4.1/bin\" >> /etc/environment"",`